# Does the Swiss Family Pass work for siblings?

Tags: trains, tickets, switzerland

I cannot find a definitive answer for this anywhere. Swiss Family Passes say they give free travel to a child under 16 travelling with a "parent". Another website says "parent or legal guardian". I am going to Switzerland in April with my brother. Can I use a family pass to get him free travel if I get an Adult Travel Pass? He is 15, I am 23.

Comment: @pnuts could be the case of a bad translation from German

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's official. I've had an email from the Swiss Travel System:

> Thank you for your email and your interest in Swiss Travel System.
>
> Unfortunately, the Swiss Family Card is only valid for children
>   travelling with their parents. Therefore, if you travel without your
>   parents the card is not available.
>
> In that case we recommend you to buy a Swiss Travel Pass for children
>   for your brother (50% discounted to the normal/adults fare) and a
>   Swiss Travel Pass Youth for you.

Answer (score 1):

It is now possible to get a "Carte Enfant Accompagné" (accompanied (?) Child Card (?)) wich allows a designated adult to travel with children for a year at the cost of 30.- CHF.
I got one for each of my step-siblings and the only thing I needed was their ID/Passport.
N.B.: I'm Swiss as are my step-siblings and I'm holder of the "AG" (yearly or monthly public transport flatrate(?)) so it might not be a thing for tourists.